# SED on Bash Script : how to replace text with special character that come from variable on Bash script

Tags: bash, sed

first, there is a variable that contain special character on bash script. here is the example.
list.txt :

```
user = root
password = 1234
```

Bash Script :

```
#!/bin/sh
var1 = var&2018+&
find . -name "list.txt" -exec sed -i "s/1234/"$var1"/g" {} +
```

when i executed the script, the result is : var12342018+1234.

Update 1 (answer by Oliv) :

```
var1='var&2018+&'
find . -name "*list.txt" -exec bash -c 'sed -i "s/1234/$2/g" $1' _ {} "$var1" \;
```

and the result still : password = var12342018+1234

maybe anyone can help me. thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First you need to quote your `var1` variable.

You can use `bash -c` in your `find` command in order to give the password as a variable:

```
 var1='var\&2018+\&'
 find . -name "list.txt" -exec bash -c 'sed -i "s/1234/$2/g" $1' _ {} "$var1" \;
```

Comment: it doesnt work. i've put quote at the variable but still getting the & symbol as matched string

Comment: @Ryan Can you please update your question with you now get and what you would expect? It's difficult to see what's going based on your comment.

Comment: i have updated the question, i expect to insert '&' character as mentioned in variable 'var1'. thank you

Comment: @Ryan answer updated: The `&` needs to be escaped.

Comment: ahh ya, forgot about escaped slash. it works! thank you

Answer (score 0):

it might help you understand the problem you are having to know that `&` is a special character that represent the whole match of your regexp.

since `1234` is found, you are replacing it with `var12342018+1234`, the two `&` is becoming the matched string.

the other point I'd like to make is really a personal preference, but using `find ... -exec` with `{}`, i don't like this syntax, I usually end it with `\;`

I prefer using xargs

`find . -name list.txt | xargs sed -i 's/1234/var&2018+&/g'`

note the ending g would replace it as many times as it is found...

also this might be obvious.. I don't know how many `list.txt` file you have in your subtree, but if you only have one, you don't need `find`.

`sed -i 's/pattern/replacement/options' filename`

Comment: yes i know my problem. also using your example  with xargs will end with same problem